# Error when exporting to Excel from ReportViewer on production but not in development

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application that uses the built-in ReportViewer control to display a local report file on a web page. The ReportViewer is bound to a Typed DataSet, which is populated via an ObjectDataSource, which queries a stored procedure on a SQL 2005 database. The user can come to the page, set a variety of parameters, and then view the report.

Everything works splendidly when viewing the report in the ReportViewer. The data is loaded into the grid as expected. However, the Export to Excel option that's built into the ReportViewer control does *not* work. Namely, when exporting I am greeted with the exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Generated: Mon, 24 Oct 2011 22:40:57 GMT

Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.WrapperReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReportControlSource.RenderReport(String format, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection additionalParams, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ExportOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The two things that perplex me is:

1. Why is the export failing when the data is clearly loaded without error from the underlying database, and
2. The export works fine in the staging environment, **even when I point my development environment connection string to the production database!** Why is it that I can export the exact same data in my development environment but not in production?

Any ideas what's going on here? My Googling turned up a lot of discussions on people using the full-blown SSRS with remote reports, but I was unable to find any potential workarounds for local report files.

Thanks

Comment: What operating systems are test and prod? 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: What version of the Micorsoft.ReportViewer.WebForm.dll are you using?